# What does "G" mean right after a flight number in a boarding pass?

Tags: usa, air-travel, tickets, terminology, alaska-airlines

Example of a boarding pass from Alaska Airlines from SFO (San Francisco International Airport) to GEG (Spokane International Airport).

[image]

The flight is [Alaska Airlines 2233](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/ASA2233).

What does the G mean right after a flight number in a boarding pass? I added the vertical red arrow to point to the G.

Comment: I don't have any proof of this, but my semi-educated hunch is that if you check the details of your fare, you'll find that your booking was priced based on fare class G.

Comment: Was the flight operated by Alaska or was it code shared with other airline?

Comment: @NeanDerThal the boarding pass says “Operated by Horizon Air”.

Comment: When a flight incurs significant operational issues which ends up with it being delayed enough that there are two flights with the same number operating on the same day, or if an extra “rescue” flight is added, it is common for one of the flights to get a slightly different number, often suffixed with an A, though. It mostly happens for long haul flights. Do you remember any such issues on that flight?

Comment: It’s a weird place to put it on a boarding pass, but it’s indeed likely it’s the fare class (it usually appears somewhere in the boarding pass).

Comment: @jcaron isn’t it more common to change the flight number (say 92233) to avoid ATC miscalls?

Comment: @jcaron Thanks, no such issues on that flight.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero it may depend on the airline and/or countries involved, but at least on the passenger side, I’ve only seen letter suffixes (and not very often, really). Not sure if the call sign remains aligned, but the “conflicting” flights are generally not in the same ATC area at the same time.

Comment: @ZachLipton I ran into another of my Alaska Airlines boarding passes, for which I did know the fare class, and you're correct: G was the fare class. Can you please add the answer? Otherwise I'll do it next week. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`G` was indeed the fare class, as [Zach Lipton](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton) and [jcaron](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30703/jcaron) hypothesized in the comments.

I found another boarding pass from Alaska Airlines with `V` as the fare class: the `V` was also appended to the flight number on the boarding pass:

[image]